# Local SSL CA always expires 30 days after creation

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl, certificate-authority

I'm following similar steps as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297139/how-do-you-sign-a-certificate-signing-request-with-your-certification-authority) to create a local CA.

Despite setting the `default_days` option to 1825 (days) in my config file, the resulting CA certificate is always set to expire 30 days after creation.

I'm confirming this by viewing the resulting PEM file with 

`openssl x509 -in ./cacert.pem -text -noout`

Here is the config file I'm using to create the CA certificate:

```
HOME            = .
RANDFILE        = $ENV::HOME/.rnd

####################################################################
[ ca ]
default_ca    = CA_default      # The default ca section

[ CA_default ]

default_days     = 1825         # how long to certify for
default_crl_days = 30           # how long before next CRL
default_md       = sha256       # use public key default MD
preserve         = no           # keep passed DN ordering

x509_extensions = ca_extensions # The extensions to add to the cert

email_in_dn     = no            # Don't concat the email in the DN
copy_extensions = copy          # Required to copy SANs from CSR to cert

base_dir      = ./CA
certificate   = $base_dir/cacert.pem        # The CA certifcate
private_key   = $base_dir/private/cakey.pem # The CA private key
new_certs_dir = $base_dir/newcerts          # Location for new certs after signing
database      = $base_dir/index.txt    # Database index file
serial        = $base_dir/serial   # The current serial number

unique_subject = no  # Set to 'no' to allow creation of
                     # several certificates with same subject.

####################################################################
[ req ]
default_bits       = 4096
default_keyfile    = cakey.pem
distinguished_name = ca_distinguished_name
x509_extensions    = ca_extensions
string_mask        = utf8only

####################################################################
[ ca_distinguished_name ]
countryName         = Country Name (2 letter code)
countryName_default = US

stateOrProvinceName         = State or Province Name (full name)
stateOrProvinceName_default = CA

localityName                = Locality Name (eg, city)
localityName_default        = Bakersfield

organizationName            = Organization Name (eg, company)
organizationName_default    = Some Company

organizationalUnitName         = Organizational Unit (eg, division)
organizationalUnitName_default = Some Org Unit

commonName         = Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name)
commonName_default = some-local-CA

emailAddress         = Email Address
emailAddress_default = netadmin@domain.com

####################################################################
[ ca_extensions ]

subjectKeyIdentifier   = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid:always, issuer
basicConstraints       = critical, CA:true
keyUsage               = keyCertSign, cRLSign

####################################################################
[ signing_policy ]
countryName            = optional
stateOrProvinceName    = optional
localityName           = optional
organizationName       = optional
organizationalUnitName = optional
commonName             = supplied
emailAddress           = optional

####################################################################
[ signing_req ]
subjectKeyIdentifier   = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid,issuer
basicConstraints       = CA:FALSE
keyUsage               = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
```

I then create the local CA with this command (same directory):

```
openssl req -x509 -config ./openssl-ca.cnf -newkey rsa:4096 -sha256 -nodes -out cacert.pem -outform PEM
```

I tried setting the `default_crl_days` option to something other than 30 and it didn't seem to have any effect.

How do I specify the expiration date (or number of days until expiration) for my local CA?

Comment: If you look at that post closely you'll see the CA cert is only valid for 30 days as well.  @slm's answer is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the setup I have for generating a CA and CA-INT I get the following for my validity dates:

```
   Validity
        Not Before: Jan 28 03:28:40 2018 GMT
        Not After : Jan 23 03:28:40 2038 GMT
```

What I came to discover is that I could only get this to work by passing it in to `openssl` directly via the `-days` switch.

For example:

```
openssl req -config $topDir/openssl.cnf \
      -key $ca_key_file \
      -new -x509 -days 7300 -sha256 -extensions v3_ca \
      -out $ca_cert_file -passin pass:casecret \
      -subj "/C=US/ST=NC/L=Raleigh/O=APPS Security/OU=APPS/CN=APPS CA"
```

Comment: Remember 20 years -- or 20x365 days -- from 2018 is after the Y2038 cutoff, and may lead to problems with some programs, systems, or devices, although less often than it used to.

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the linked question/answer, the poster is using `openssl req` to generate the certificate.  Without a specific `-days` option on the command line, the command defaults to 30 days:

> -days n
>
> When the -x509 option is being used this specifies the number of days to certify the certificate for, otherwise it is ignored. n
>   should be a positive integer. The default is 30 days.

The same goes for the `x509` command:

> -days arg
>
> Specifies the number of days to make a certificate valid for. The default is 30 days.

`default_days`, `default_startdate` and `default_enddate` within the options file are only used with the `openssl ca` command (not `req` or `x509`).

Comment: Actually not; for the _CA_ cert the linked answer says, and this Q repeats, `openssl req -x509 ... -newkey ...` (which implies `-new`). However, `req -x509` doesn't use `ca` settings any more than `x509 -req` does; as you say, only `ca` uses `ca` settings. And `req -x509` also has `-days` option.